# Parent div does not scroll on dragging a child inside of it

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I have a parent `div` with many child divs.

I want when a child `div` is dragged inside the parent `div`, then the parent `div` to scroll. When the parent `div` is the body, it works. But I want it to work with my own parent "content" `div`.

Here is a js example of the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/yzx4ft46/

Any ideas why it doesn't work?

Comment: `appendTo: '#content'` and `position: relative` for #content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the parent div must have `position: relative` and it started working:)

Since the cloned element has position `absolute` and absolute positioning is positioned according to the first parent element with other then static positioning, then it is needed the parent element to have `position: relative`.